# Symfony 4 - GET /hi not found

Tags: symfony, symfony4

This is my routes.yaml file

```
schedulePosts:
path: /schedulePosts
controller: App\Controller\PostController::startSchedulePosts

hi:
path: /hi
controller: App\Controller\PostController:hi
```

And this is my PostController

```
    class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function startSchedulePosts(){

        echo "<html><p>Starting...</p></html>";


        return new Response("<html><p>Done...</p></html>");

    }

    public function hi(){
        return new Response("<html><p>Hi</p></html>");
    }
}
```

When I run my local web server and head to the /schedulePosts endpoint I get the correct response but when I head to the /hi endpoint I get a No Route Found for "GET /hi".

I can't figure out what is going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you have only one colon (:) at the controller for the :hi in the file routes.yaml, while you have two colon (:) at the controller for the ::startSchedulePosts.

Do you try to have two colon for the ::hi ?

Comment: It worked. Can't believe that a missing colon was the problem. Thank you!